# Compute limit with the help of MacLaurin series expansion

Tags: calculus

Compute $$\lim _{x \to 0} \dfrac{e^{2x^2}-1}{x^2}$$ with the aid of a MacLaurin series expansion.

Comment: MacLaurin is overkill. The limit is twice the derivative of $e^{2x^2}=e^t$ at $t=0$. (So just one MacLaurin coefficient suffices.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** The problem has been corrected. We keep the original solution, and add a solution to the corrected problem below.

**Hint:** We have 
$$e^{(2x)^2}=1+(2x)^2+\frac{(2x)^4}{2!}+\frac{(2x)^6}{3!}+\cdots.$$
(Just write down the Maclaurin expansion of $e^t$, and everywhere in the expansion replace $t$ by $(2x)^2$.) Thus
$$\frac{e^{(2x)^2}-1}{x^2}=4+O(x^2).$$

**Answer to corrected problem:** This asks for 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{2x^2}-1}{x^2}.$$
We have
$$e^{2x^2}=1+2x^2+\frac{(2x^2)^2}{2!}+\frac{(2x^2)^3}{3!}+\cdots.$$
Subtract $1$, divide by $x^2$. We get $2$ plus a bunch of terms that have $x$'s in them. As $x\to 0$, these terms approach $0$, so the limit is $2$.

**Another way:** We used the Maclaurin expansion mechanically in the solution, because it is a nice tool that it is very important to know about. But there are simpler ways. Let $t=x^2$. Then we want to find
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{e^{2t}-1}{t}.$$
Let $f(t)=e^{2t}$. Note that $f(0)=1$. Then by the definition of the derivative, 
$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t}=f'(0).$$

In our case, $f'(t)=2e^{2t}$, so $f'(0)=2$, and our limit is $2$.

Comment: I am not sure how you got 4+0(x^2). Could you explain?

Comment: After you divide, what's after $4$ is $x^2(a+bx^2+cx^4+\cdots)$. The stuff inside the brackets approaches $0$ as $x\to 9$. We actually don't need this, enough to say we get $4+o(1)$, that is, $4$ plus something that approaches $0$. More crudely, and somewhat inaccurately, when we divide we get $4$ plus stuff that has $x$'s in it, and that stuff approaches $0$.

Comment: So how would you find the limit? Are you taking the limit of 4+o(1)?

Comment: After we subtract $1$ and divide by $x^2$, we have $4$ plus something that is approaching $0$. The limit is $4$.

Comment: when I put 4 as my answer it does not count it as an answer, so according to my homework 4 is the wrong answer?

Comment: @user85172: Three possibilities (i) the problem as typed is not the one that was asked or (ii) they made a mistake or (iii) there was a computer glitch. The answer to the problem as typed is instantaneous, one little look and the $4$ pops out.

Comment: I noticed the problem it should be 2x^2 not (2x)^2

Comment: I have added to the old answer two solutions to the revised problem. The answer changes, the limit is now $2$.

Comment: That is correct thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

We have 
$$e^{(2x)^2}=1+(2x)^2+\frac{(2x)^4}{2!}+\frac{(2x)^6}{3!}+\cdots.$$
(Just write down the Maclaurin expansion of $e^t$, and everywhere in the expansion replace $t$ by $(2x)^2$.) Thus
$$\frac{e^{(2x)^2}-1}{x^2}=\frac{(2x)^2+\frac{(2x)^4}{2!}+..}{x^2}\cdots.$$
Now take x^2 common and cancel . The higher power terms will become zero and we'll get the answer as 4 
4 is the answer to this limit.